# Can GridSearchCV be used for unsupervised learning?

Tags: python, outlier, grid-search, isolation-forest

im trying to build an outlier detector to find outliers in test data. That data varies a bit (more test channels, longer/shorter testing).

First im applying the train test split because i want to use grid search for hypertuning. This is timeseries data from multiple sensors and i removed the time column beforehand.

```
X shape : (25433, 17)
y shape : (25433, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=(0))
```

Standardize afterwards and then i changed them into an int Array because GridSearch doesnt seem to like continuous data. This surely can be done better, but i want this to work before i optimize the coding.

```
'X'
mean = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = mean.transform(X_train)
X_test = mean.transform(X_test)

X_train = np.round(X_train,2)*100
X_train = X_train.astype(int)
X_test = np.round(X_test,2)*100
X_test = X_test.astype(int)

'y'
yeah = StandardScaler().fit(y_train)
y_train = yeah.transform(y_train)
y_test = yeah.transform(y_test)
y_train = np.round(y_train,2)*100
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = np.round(y_test,2)*100
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
```

I chose the IForrest because its fast, has pretty good results and can handle huge data sets (i currently only use a chunk of the data for testing). Setting Up the GridSearchCV:

```
clf = IForest(random_state=47, behaviour='new',
          n_jobs=-1)

param_grid = {'n_estimators': [20,40,70,100], 
              'max_samples': [10,20,40,60], 
              'contamination': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001], 
              'max_features': [5,15,30], 
              'bootstrap': [True, False]}

fbeta = make_scorer(fbeta_score,
                    average = 'micro',
                    needs_proba=True,
                    beta=1)

grid_estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, 
                                              param_grid,
                                              scoring=fbeta,
                                              cv=5,
                                              n_jobs=-1,
                                              return_train_score=True,
                                              error_score='raise',
                                              verbose=3)

grid_estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**The Problem:**

I cant fit the  grid_estimator.
GridSearchCV needs an y_argument, without `y` its passing me the "missing y_true" error.
What should be used as a target here ? Atm i just passed an important data column to `y` for testing, but im getting this error that i dont understand:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput 
targets
```

I also got the advice that the i need a scoring function and the iForest doesnt have one.
I couldnt find useful information for this, are there any helpful guides or info that can help me ?

Comment: In comments on [your SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73867399/10495893), I pointed out a number of technical errors, and said that I think most of them can be worked around. The main question for this site (IMO) is partially stated in the last paragraph: "what is a useful metric to use for (unsupervised) outlier detection models (esp. isolation forest)?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal of `GridSearchCV` is to iterate over (hence search) all possible combinations (hence grid) of hyper parameters and evaluate a model on a cross-validation (hence CV). You do need some score to compare models with different sets of hyper parameters. If you can come out with some reasonable way to score a model after the fit, you can write a custom scoring function. If this scoring function does not require target (y) to be computed, you can simply pass an array of zeros to `GridSearchCV`. The example of such scorer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186702/using-gridsearchcv-with-isolationforest-for-finding-outliers).

<s>Otherwise, if you use some supervised model on a filtered (by IsolationTrees) data, you can do that using Pipelines, and run GridSearchCV on that, see [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html) in sklearn docs:</s>

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

estimators = [('filter_data_it', IsolationForest()),
              ('clf', LogisticRegression())]

pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
param_grid = dict(filter_data_it__max_features=[5,15,30], clf__C=[0.1, 10])
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid)
```

recall, that when you use Pipelines you need to prepend `param_grid` with the name of the pipeline step.

UPD1. As stated in the comments IF don't have method `transform`, thus simple chaining will not work. The way IF works is by predicting outliers and not by filtering the data (you are supposed to filter outliers afterwards). However, there is a way around this problem. We need to create a new class with transform method, which will run IF, and filter the data based on its predictions. I will update the code snippet.

It turns out there is no clear way to adapt sklearn API for that purpose, as stated in these questions, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896178/sklearn-have-an-estimator-that-filters-samples), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602489/using-a-transformer-estimator-to-transform-the-target-labels-in-sklearn-pipeli), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24917063/9697134) answer suggest a solution, however it is relatively complex. Thus, I suggest you proceed with scorer example.